# Компиляция в Borland C++

Tags: borland, c++

У меня есть Borland C++. Мне нужно произвести компиляцию. Как это сделать? Помогите плз.

Answer (score 2):

Жмете F9 и все компилируется, линкуется и запускается. Или выдается список ошибок. К сожалению, большАя часть этого списка обязана своим появлением какой-нибудь ошибке, случившейся раньше (например, пропущенной скобке блока или точке с запятой). 
Можете сначала нажать Alt+F9 - компиляция текущего файла; или Ctrl+F9 - создаете объектный модуль без линковки. Это - если Вы работаете в ИСР.

Comment: плюс еще программа будет запускаться только на компьютерах, на которых установлен билдер, чтобы этого не произошло, необходимо :  
Project->Options:  
Compiler->Release  
Packages->Build with runtime packages (убрать галочку)  
Linker->Use dynamic RTL (убрать галочку)  
потом уже F9

Comment: 1.Программа будет запускаться на копьютерах, где установлены пакеты и библиотеки времени запуска. Чтобы выяснить, какие из них необходимо включить в инсталлятор, запустите "TDUMP.exe имя-приложения>Имя_выходного файла". В разделе IMPORTS выходного файла найдете их названия.
2. Если делать так, как пишет @чипик, то нажимать надо не F9, а Build Project; тогда будут учтены Ваши изменения в OPTIONS, и пограмма будет создана в форме Stand Alone. Но размеры ее окажутся в 10...20 раз больше.

Answer (score 1):

нужно нажать кажется F9, и в папке з СРР файлом появится фал програми ЕХЕ, 5если конечно в тексте програми не ошибок,  также компилировать можно з помощу пункта меню Compile (F9)

Answer (score 0):

Насколько помню, там должна быть кнопочка на панели и пунктик в меню. Ищите.